# spit list into strings

Tags: python, string, list

I have a list of strings:

```
['TTGGGAGAA', 'TTGGGAGCA', 'TTGGGAGTA']
```

And I want to test if a string is present in this list: 
So test for example if 'GTA' (= subsequence) is present in my list

I tried:

```
OK = subsequence in list 
if OK == True: 
    print (true)
else: pass
```

But it doesn't work. Can somebody help me?

Comment: if you are looking for a subsequence I'd recommend a for loop to iterate over each word and see if the subsequence is in a word

Comment: If you want to see if any item in your list contains the subsequence, you could use [`any`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any). For example: `if any(subsequence in x for x in mylist): print("found")`

Comment: Why would you not write `if subsequence in list:`? It's not like `OK` is a meaningful name.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not correct, as it will compare the entire element of the list with `subsequence`. Instead, do this,

```
for word in list:
    if subsequence in word:
        OK = True
        break
```

You can compress this into one line using the [`any()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any) function. Do this using,

```
OK = any(subsequence in word for word in list)
```

Comment: OK, that worked! but now: what if my subsequence is also a list of strings. So I am looking for a match between 2 lists. If there is some substring identical; print 'OK'

Comment: Will you always compare the first string with the first subsequence?

Comment: Add the comment in the question instead, or best ask a new question

Answer (score 4):

You are looking for a *sub-sequence*, so

```
subsequence in list
```

doesn't work because it checks against the *whole* list.

You should do:

```
OK = any(subsequence in l for l in list)
```

Note: I don't recommend using "list" as a variable name, as it's a preserved keyword in Python.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with a list comprehension like this:

```
a = ['TTGGGAGAA', 'TTGGGAGCA', 'TTGGGAGTA']

any(["GTA" in x for x in a])
```

This will return `True` if there is any sequence inside the array that has `"GTA"` in it.

Answer (score 0):

```
alist = ['TTGGGAGAA', 'TTGGGAGCA', 'TTGGGAGTA', 'TGA']

print('GTA' in alist) # False 
print('TGA' in alist) # True as TGA is a list element

# this is what you probably want
# string search instead of list search
print('GTA' in '|'.join(alist)) # True
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a sample code for your reference, please help to check whether it is for you.
It is the for compare one list in another list.

```
listab =  ['a', 'b']
listabc = ['a', 'b', 'c']
if all(each in listabc for each in listab):
    print "It is the subsequence"
else:
    print "Not a subsequence"
```

Answer (score -2):

One way to accomplish this task is by using regural expressions.

That way you can search within strings in the list for your pattern.

Below is a simple example:

```
import re
pattern = re.compile('GTA')
src_list = ['TTGGGAGAA', 'TTGGGAGCA', 'TTGGGAGTA']
for element in src_list
    if re.findall(pattern, element):
        print(True)
        break
```

Note the re.compile compiles the pattern so futher searches are much faster.

Comment: It looks like you overcomplicated the original problem, the ```in``` keyword is enough to answer the question and there is no need for regex.

Comment: Also you're passing the wrong arguments to `re.findall`.

Comment: @TrakJohnson the idea behind using regex is for the solution to scale as the list grows. khelwood, what would theright arguments to re.findall be?

Comment: @XeroSmith You're iterating through `src_list` using the variable `element`, but you're using `src_list` instead of `element` in your call to `findall`.

Comment: @khelwood, thanks, I see the error. I have corrected it accordingly. I still stand by the argument for a scalable solution.

Comment: There is no benefit to using regular expressions for a requirement this simple. It is no more "scalable" than simply using the `in` operator.

Comment: @khelwood I see your point, in the end, I'm still just checking each element  in the list for the subsequence. Thanks for clarifying that. I doff my hat to you.